# In a Python Bokeh Legend, How do I Change the display format of numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, charts, bokeh

I'm using Pandas 0.18.1 and Bokeh 0.12.2 in Python 3.5 to create simple bar charts using Bokeh's high level charts interface. The value of each bar chart is a floating point number converted to a percentage, then rounded to 1 decimal point using Pandas' round() method, however, when Bokeh creates the legend, it will display the entire length of the float. e.x.

```
job_type = clean.groupby('job_type').count()
job_type['job_type_pct'] = (job_type['job_id'] / job_type['job_id'].sum()) * 100
print(job_type['job_type_pct'])
job_type.head()
```

This results in the display of

```
job_type
freelance     17.7
fulltime      80.3
internship    2.0
Name: job_type_pct, dtype: float64
```

However, when I plot this, the Bokeh legend displays

```
(17.699999999999999, 'freelance')
(80.299999999999997, 'fulltime')
(2.0, 'internship')
```

I get that this is the result of floating point arithmetic, but I would like to format the legend so that the numbers have a consistent format something similar to Python's `format(float, '.2f')`. Is there a way to force a Bokeh Legend to display only a subset of the numbers?